# jenkins build fail due to ambiguous java interface

Tags: java, interface, jenkins, compilation

I have the following Java classes/interfaces:

Under folder ./common:
1. com.xyz.hrdept.common.dao.DatabaseUtilsDAO (interface)
2. com.xyz.hrdept.common.dao.hibernate.DatabaseUtilsDAOHibernate (class, implements the above interface).

Under folder ./WebApplication/src
3. 
    com.xyz.hrdept.dao.DAOFactory    // abstract class
    {
        DatabaseUtilsDAO getDatabaseUtilsDAO();
    }

4.
    com.xyz.hrdept.dao.hibernate.hibernate.HibernateDAOFactory extends DAOFactory
    {
      DatabaseUtilsDAO getDatabaseUtilsDAO()
      {
          return new DatabaseUtilsDAOHibernate();
      }
    }

They compile successfully in my local Intellij environment, but failed on Jenkins server
with the following error message:
/WebApplication/src/com/xyz/hrdept/dao/hibernate/HibernateDAOFactory.java:70: error: reference to DatabaseUtilsDAO is ambiguous, both interface com.xyz.hrdept.dao.DatabaseUtilsDAO in com.xyz.hrdept.dao and interface com.xyz.hrdept.common.dao.DatabaseUtilsDAO in com.xyz.hrdept.common.dao match

There is no com.xyz.hrdept.dao.DatabaseUtilsDAO interface. I do not know how the server assumes that.

On Jenkins server, I include to modules to build, one for common, one for WebApplication.

I have been spending a lot of time on it, does anybody have a clue and help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Environment variables in the script in local environment and on Jenkins server have different definitions.